# i want to make a chained drop down of my django model

Tags: django, dropdown, chained

please i want a chained dropdown in such away that it is only when you click on country that state will also be displayed

```
class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PollingUnitModel
        fields = ['name','country', 'state', 'lga','ward']
```

i have been thinking of using autocomplete but i don't understand how it works
from dal import autocomplete

```
from django import forms


class PollinForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PollingUnitModel
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'country': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete')
```

Comment: Do you want it on single page without reloading like ajax or you want custom form for each type ?

Comment: Custom form for each type